# How to add images one on another image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have small requirement: I need add image over(up) the another image through javascript. Please give me the suggestion!

[image: A chicken]

```
function sampleImage()
{     
    document.getElementById('img1').innerHTML='<img src="C:\Users\rajasekhark\Desktop\assets\images\Cock.png" />';
}
```

Comment: Questions generally have a `?` in them somewhere. In it's current state, your post is absolutely useless. Add more detail, explain what you actually want to do, and show what you've attempted  so far.

Comment: You need to provide a clearer question.  Also, you need to accept some of the previous answers (when people see you don't accept answers, they don't feel motivated to help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do (I saw jquery tag):

```
$("#img1 img").first().prop("src", "C:\Users\rajasekhark\Desktop\assets\images\Cock.png");
```

And an advice: DO NOT use full path to your local disk ...

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose the two images in a `<div>` and then use the following CSS attributes:

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

​#img2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/C8hh4/

The second image must be a *sibling* of the first, it cannot be a descendent because that's not legal HTML.  The `<div>` needs to have `relative` position otherwise `#img2`'s absolute position will be calculated relative to the closest ancestor that *doesn't* have the default `static` position.

The value for `top` should be half of the difference between the outer image's height and the inner image's height, and likewise for the left / width.

If your content is static, calculate those values by hand.  If it's dynamic, use JS to set the style:

```
var img1 = $('#img1')[0];
var img2 = $('#img2')[0];

var top = 0.5 * (img1.height - img2.height);
var left = 0.5 * (img1.width - img2.width);

$(img2).css({top: top, left: left});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why javascript? Of course, you could use a canvas and paint them over each other, but I would recommend simple CSS:

```
<img
  style="padding: 20px 7px, background: url('/some/frame.png')"
  src="/cock.jpg"
  width="50px" height="40px"
/>
```

You might use a class for that, the inline style is just shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use relative positioning.
Stack the images on top of each other and set `position:relative;top:VALUE;`
Value should be -HalfHeightOfBackgroundImage-HalfHeightOfForegroundImage.

Another approach whould be wrapping the foreground image in a div and setting the the background image as the `background-image`.

Comment: relative position won't work well - it's calculated relative (!) to the element's _expected_ position.

Comment: because to stack the images on top of each other in the first place the second one needs to have an _absolute_ position relative to its container (and the first image).

Comment: Quick and Dirty: `<img src="http://www.deshow.net/d/file/travel/2009-06/germany-landscape-605-2.jpg" /><br />
        <img style="position:relative;top:-550;left:490" src="http://www.teezeh.de/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/IE.jpg" />`

Comment: like I said, it doesn't work _well_.  It's easier if you know that both images _start_ in the same (absolute) coordinates.

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah it doesn't work really well, but it does. My preferred approach would be working with a background image.

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery option would be

```
$("#img1").prop("src","blahblah.jpg");
```

Although I don't really understand your question.

If you mean that you need to change the image on hover then perhaps this will help...

```
$("#img1").hover(
    function () {
    $(this).prop("src","newImage.jpg");
    }, 
    function () {
    $(this).prop("src","originalImage.jpg");
});
```

EDIT:

OK... 
What you need is a div with the green flashcard as the background image. And place the cock image in that div but set to display:none;

Then on hover just show the image of the cock.

```
$("#containerDiv").hover(
    function () {
    $(this).find("img").show();
    }, 
    function () {
    $(this).find("img").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i have two images now, one is green color flashcard and another one is cock.Now i need to insert the cock into the flashcard.as show the image

Comment: if you don't understand the question, why are you answering it..?