# Stitching several canvas images together into one image in canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to stitch several images together into a one image.

Below are my images.

1st image :

[image]

2nd image :

[image]

3rd image :

[image]

4th image :

[image]

I want to stitch above all images into one like below

Final image :

[image]

I tried below code

```
let imgEle1 = document.querySelectorAll(".image")[0];
let imgEle2 = document.querySelectorAll(".image")[1];
let imgEle3 = document.querySelectorAll(".image")[2];
let imgEle4 = document.querySelectorAll(".image")[3];
let resEle = document.querySelector(".result");
var context = resEle.getContext("2d");
let BtnEle = document.querySelector(".Btn");
BtnEle.addEventListener("click", () => {
resEle.width = imgEle1.width;
resEle.height = imgEle1.height;
context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
context.drawImage(imgEle1, 0, 0);
context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
context.drawImage(imgEle2, 0, 0);
context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
context.drawImage(imgEle3, 0, 0);
context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
context.drawImage(imgEle4, 0, 0);
});
```

but getting output as below

[image]

Comment: And what did you try so far? Post the code with specific errors..

Comment: You can take a look at this [How to add images one on another image using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179468/how-to-add-images-one-on-another-image-using-javascript)

Comment: Your Final image looks like the images have some offset, but when you draw all have same location 0,0 `drawImage(imgEle#, 0, 0)` ...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, your calls to `drawImage` are all in the same location...
For the effect you show, the solution is to add a bit of offset to the locations.

Here is some sample code:

```js
var image = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/></svg>`;

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.globalAlpha = 0.5;

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(image);
img.onload = function() {
  // draw images with offset
  context.translate(40, 40)
  context.drawImage(img, -20,   0);
  context.drawImage(img,  20,   0);
  context.drawImage(img,   0, -20);
  context.drawImage(img,   0,  20);
  
  // draw images with NO offset
  context.translate(140, 0)
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=600 height=160></canvas>
```

I'm using just one hardcoded SVG image to show what is possible, but you can certainly add other images latter like you have in your sample code.

Comment: thank you Helder Sepulveda
Using offset i can get above output.
is there any way where i can find the proper same point of image.
means as in my 4 images there are inner circle on which i am drawing whole image 
is it possible to get that?

Comment: Hello @Pran, ... there might be a way to get that ... but that is a completely different question. You should post a separate question about that, and add precise details of what you know about that inner circle, what is constant on the images, what can change.